# LINQ statement as if condition

Tags: c#

I saw a piece of code which was written like this:

```
if (from n in numbers select n where n = 5)
```

However, I tried writing something like this but came across errors (bare in mind the code sample may not be exactly as above as I am typing from memory). How can I write code like the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use this as a condition, you need to have an expression that returns a boolean.  Most likely, this means checking to see if there are any numbers that meet your criteria.

You probably wanted to do:

```
if ( (from n in numbers where n == 5 select n).Any() )
{
   // Do something
}
```

Personally, I'd avoid the language integrated syntax, and write this as:

```
if (numbers.Where(n => n == 5).Any())
{
   // Do something
}
```

Or even:

```
if (numbers.Any(n => n == 5))
{
   // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was probably something like this:

```
if ((from n in numbers where n == 5 select n).Any())
```

This can also be written as

```
if (numbers.Any(n => n == 5))
```

It is possible, but highly unlikely, that the code was actually

```
if (from n in numbers where n == 5 select n)
```

and `numbers` was a custom non-enumerable type with a `Select` method that returns `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

if requires boolean expression.
Try with boolean expression in *select* part.

Comment: Wrong.  That would return `IEnumerable<bool>`.